# Eclipse C++ content assist, auto activation

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, intellisense

I have noticed in Eclipse that content assist kicks in after inserting -> or . or ::

I really like this feature, but I was hoping that it would be a little more flexible and auto activate after every 2-3 character typed. An example of this is in Code::Blocks. It allows you to auto activate content assist after a certain number of chars typed. Another example of this is in Visual Studio while using Visual Assist X, "Whole Tomato".

Is it possible to somehow enable this for Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I havn't seen a setting to auto-activate the content assist, for other than . :: and -> However, Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to autocomplete or bring up the content assist  , e.g. after you typed 2-3 chars.